# MAX of a Date column using HQL with inner join

Tags: sql, hibernate, date, max

I am trying to find the maximum value of a Date column in mySQL DB using hibernate query language with inner join

```
@Query("select u, CAST(MAX(o.last_modified AS DATE)) from com.dw.model.user.User as u left join com.dw.domain.order.Order as o on u.username=o.techid group by o.techid")
List<User> findUsers();
```

i am getting this error :-

`expecting CLOSE, found 'AS' near line 1, column 36` [select u, CAST(MAX(o.last_modified AS DATE)) from com.dw.model.user.User as u left join com.dw.domain.order.Order as o on u.username=o.techid group by o.techid]

Can anyone please help me out by telling me how to write this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with the query.

1) A table alias `u` was being `select`ed. Because, you are grouping by o.techid, i assume you would need it in the `select`. If you need some columns from `u`, explicitly specify them in the `select` and `group by` those columns.

2) `CAST(MAX(o.last_modified AS DATE))` should have been `CAST(MAX(o.last_modified) AS DATE)`

```
select o.techid, CAST(MAX(o.last_modified) AS DATE) 
from com.dw.model.user.User as u 
left join com.dw.domain.order.Order as o on u.username=o.techid 
group by o.techid
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help,

Comment: now i am using tthis query which is suggested by you @Query("select o.techid, CAST(MAX(o.last_modified) AS DATE) from com.dw.model.user.User as u left join com.dw.model.order.Order as o on u.username=o.techid group by o.techid")
 List<User> findUsers();

Comment: @akp but staill am facing a issue :- Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!